# SonarQube "Unable to create symbol table for" NPE

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm getting a few of:

```
[ERROR] Unable to create symbol table for : /path/to/my/File.java
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.setInferedType(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:301)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.lambda$refineType$4(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:576)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.refineType(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:572)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.lambda$visitMethodReference$5(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:954)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitMethodReference(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:939)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodReferenceTreeImpl.accept(MethodReferenceTreeImpl.java:62)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.setInferedType(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:308)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.inferArgumentTypes(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:792)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitMethodInvocation(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:248)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl.accept(MethodInvocationTreeImpl.java:96)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitLambdaExpression(BaseTreeVisitor.java:343)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitLambdaExpression(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:531)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.LambdaExpressionTreeImpl.accept(LambdaExpressionTreeImpl.java:91)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.setInferedType(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:308)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.inferArgumentTypes(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:792)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitMethodInvocation(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:248)
    at org.sonar.java.model.expression.MethodInvocationTreeImpl.accept(MethodInvocationTreeImpl.java:96)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitReturnStatement(BaseTreeVisitor.java:173)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitReturnStatement(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:589)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.ReturnStatementTreeImpl.accept(ReturnStatementTreeImpl.java:69)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85)
    at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:77)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitMethod(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:132)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:218)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitClass(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:141)
    at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:198)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:37)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55)
    at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:62)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:105)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:84)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:114)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:108)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:182)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:242)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:240)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:232)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

All say `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` for the reason. These files are relatively large, so sorry if I have not included my `File.java, etc`

I don't know how to debug this. I tried running with `-X` to get more information out, but could not find anything that could help me.

help is appreciated

Comment: Isn't static analysis supposed to detect NPE problems like this? If only they could run some tool on their code, like sonar or sth?

Comment: @JakubBochenski I don't think the NPE exception is with my code. It's a NPE of Sonar's code while it tries to create a report.

Comment: umm... "they" was referring to the programmers who wrote sonarlint (or whatever is the runner called now)